# Add ImageSet and Images for pages/grids

Tags: acumatica

In Acumatica 5.1 is it possible to add new ImageSets and Images for buttons?

For example, in the custom application I'm working on I'd like to create a new image for a few of the buttons that show above the grids.

The documentation/information references ImageSets and ImageID's w/in the set but there isn't a reference on how to create new ones (if possible)

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I propose you to try the following within declaration of your button:

```
 public PXAction<PMTask> SyncPMTaskWithJira;
 [PXButton(CommitChanges = true, 
 ImageUrl = "https://i.stack.imgur.com/uIcP0.jpg?s=64&g=1",
 DisabledImageUrl = 
 "https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/1d02905a73147ffff3eb0e953a609abd?s=328&d=identicon&r=PG",
    HoverImageUrl = "https://i.stack.imgur.com/uIcP0.jpg?s=64&g=1")]
    [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Sync With Jira")]
    protected void syncPMTaskWithJira()
    {}
```

Comment: I actually was attempting that last night when I was looking at this again.  Interestingly enough, the icons never would show a logo when linked via ImageUrl but that might be a build related issue.    The one thing nice about the image sets though is the savings on having to download each image individually and having to only deploy one file in the customization.

Comment: I'm going to go ahead and accept this as the answer.  This isn't exactly what I was hoping for but this method does work (to an extent).